# Late 2008 Unibody Mac Book - SSD Integral SATA lll Install

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hard-drive

I am trying to install a new SSD Integral hard drive in to my late 2008 unibody MacBook  but all I get when I use the command R combination is a flashing question mark in a file.

Does anyone know what the problem is or what that symbol means?

Comment: Do you have access to another Mac? If so, you'll need to try making a boot/install USB on that. The 08 cannot boot to internet recovery. Alternatively, if the old drive is still working, you can boot to that & install to the new drive. Or, as a long shot,  if you have the original CDs that came with the machine, you could install from there.

Comment: Thanks the other issue is the MacBook won’t recognise the SSD drive.

Comment: That would be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> reinstalls macOS from a built-in Recovery partition your new SSD does not contain.

To update over the Internet, use <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>.

More information about using the recovery system at this [Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314)

Comment: An 08 can't boot to Internet Recovery. That started in around 2011.

Comment: Thanks, Tetsujin. I was looking for that info, but could not find it.